# Error authorization when using the parameters in the request to WooCommerce REST API via Retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, woocommerce, retrofit

I connect to the Internet-store WooCommerce through a WooCommerce REST API using Java Retrofit library.

When I build simple queries such as "example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories" or "example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/orders" - all OK - passes authentication and I get a JSON result.

I look in the logs on the Android Monitor - in the case of successful authentication to log output here this URL:
http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories?oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=ck_0fadf0f69b271063373f49a6cd942ce995d5dad4&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_timestamp=1478702999&oauth_nonce=-56787616&oauth_signature=AmEJUMnKzKxkqETQoQxd07WRvZo&page=2

But if I try to use in query parameters such as "example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories?per_page=20" or "example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/orders?page=3" - I get an error authorization 401.

I tried different variants of queries:

- add a parameter in Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories?per_page=20")
- add a parameter in the call of interface functions - Call<.....> loadCategories(@Query("per_page") Integer 20)
- add a parameter when forming an authorization string in the Interceptor after oauth_signature - .addQueryParameter("per_page", "20")

The logs URL takes the form type:
http://example.com/wp-json/wc/v1/products/categories?per_page=20&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=ck_0fadf0f69b271063373f49a6cd942ce995d5dad4&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_timestamp=1478702999&oauth_nonce=-56787616&oauth_signature=AmEJUMnKzKxkqETQoQxd07WRvZo&page=2

The error occurs when I add parameter after ? - I understand it conflicts with the authorization parameters WooCommerce?

What am I doing wrong? Or maybe it was a error WooCommerce API ?

Comment: Hi! did you ever solve this?